# Tensor Product over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

This question appeared in my exam and I could not solve it.

Let $L$ be a field, $K$ subfield of $L$. Assume that dim$_K(L)$=$m$, and $V$ be a $L-$vector space amd dim$_L(V)=n$. If as usual $\otimes_L$ denote L-vector space,

Why is $V\otimes_LK$ not well-defined in general?

What is $\dim_K(V\otimes_KL)$ in terms of $n$ and $m$, if it is well defined or explain why it is undefined.

I thought, there is no cannonical way to define $K$ as a vector space over $L$, so the dimension of tensor product in first question is undefined. I think it is not correct/sufficient. Could you please explain the details for the first and second question?

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct (except that "dimension of" is redundant; the tensor product itself is undefined).

Comment: For the second question, is it well-defined? Well, the tensor product over $K$ of two $K$-vector spaces is well-defined. Are $V$ and $L$ two $K$-vector spaces (or become such in a canonical way)? And what formulas do you know for the dimension of a tensor product of two $K$-vector spaces?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, is this correct: $\dim_KV=mn,\dim_kL=m\Rightarrow$ the dimension of given tensor product is $m^2n$?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case.